# Debugging long running Java App with endless loop

Tags: java, debugging, reflection

My Java code interprets some other code, and while processing a high-level representation of that code, it seems stuck in an endless loop. Usually, I would (if I couldn't simply find the loop by looking sharply at the code) activate debugging mode and then search for a hook into the endless loop by adding some breakpoints at runtime. However, the runtime for the program to get to that point is ~1h in standard execution mode and several hours when started in debug mode. Ideally, I would like to let the program run in standard mode (to have the speed) and then, when it reaches the endless loop, attach a debugger, which is impossible.

I have unsuccessfully tried to reproduce the problem in a smaller test. So I was thinking of adding my very own debugging method by creating a GUI and using reflection; here is the idea:

Adding a JFrame instance that is statically available to all classes in the project, that JFrame could have a method, e.g., `public void debugMe()` , that will be called from points in my code that I suspect to be part of the problem.

`debugMe()` would not do anything unless a button was pressed or similar, so I could have the speed of standard execution but still be able to inspect the app at some predefined points. `debugMe()` could use the StackWalker to identify the caller and then reflect to get and display the variables within the caller. That (especially a proper view of the variables) would be a lot of work, so I would appreciate your comments on the feasibility of this approach or any other suggestions you might have.

Comment: Have you tried using thread dump? It should be easy to find this endless loop with it. More details: https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump

Comment: This looks rather promising, had never heard of it for Java!!!

Comment: `jcmd <pid> Thread.print`